# Running Dojo DOH tests within mstest

Tags: dojo, mstest, doh

I'm required to run dojo DOH tests within a MSTest framework.  So far I haven't found any useful links except one from Stephen Walter.  A requirement is to avoid loading the test into jscript; for some tests I need to run within a browser instance I'm guessing.

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand the question enough, but if you don't want to write the tests in the javascript you are testing, its possible to use initRobot() from the dijit.robotx robot. This will let you keep the test code in a separate file. Check out this page from the [dojo toolkit reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/util/dohrobot.html) - scroll down to the **Separating Robot Test Code From Application Code** section.

Or is the problem that you don't want to use the browser to run the tests in the first place?